# Number Theory calculation problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was working through a set of lecture notes, and I saw the following line:

$u^2+5v^2 = \pm 1$ or $\pm2$, and so it follows that $v=0$.

I can't see how this line is clear, and can't see how to do this without quite a lot of effort. If someone could provide an easy explanation, that would appreciated.

Comment: This makes no sense....the quadratic form in question can never be negative and clearly takes values greater than $5$.  Presumably you left off the context?

Comment: that makes sense, I had forgotten that squares of integers are greater than or equal to zero. Sorry for wasting your time, it been a long day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $v\ne 0 $ then $u^2+5v^2 \ge 0+5= 5$

Comment: thanks, long day!